# Windows 10 + Python + Flask (fresh installations, v3+) - flask command not found

Tags: python, windows, flask

I'm running on a Windows 10 laptop, the Python and Flask are fresh up-to-date installations.

```
$ py -m flask --version
Python 3.9.1
Flask 1.1.2
Werkzeug 1.0.1
```

I'm working on a group project for school, and one of the other guys has made a basic backbone for the project (.venv, __pycache__ folders, etc.).

I'm using Git Bash in the project folder to run commands and do version control (in case this is somehow relevant). I try to get a running test for what he has going so far by following the directions given by the [Flask tutorial](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/factory/), following the examples given:

```
MINGW64 ~/Documents/CPSC 362/project/SousChef ( github directory )
$ source venv/Scripts/activate
(venv)
MINGW64 ~/Documents/CPSC 362/project/SousChef ( github directory )
$ set FLASK_APP=application
(venv)
MINGW64 ~/Documents/CPSC 362/project/SousChef ( github directory )
$ set FLASK_ENV=development
(venv)
MINGW64 ~/Documents/CPSC 362/project/SousChef ( github directory )
$ flask run
bash: flask: command not found

# I know for certain I'm doing something wrong, here,
# so I try the 'python -m flask' mentioned in the tutorial

(venv)
MINGW64 ~/Documents/CPSC 362/project/SousChef ( github directory )
$ py flask run
C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe: can't open file 
'C:\Users\Nick\Documents\CPSC 362\project\SousChef\flask': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
(venv)

MINGW64 ~/Documents/CPSC 362/project/SousChef ( github directory )
$ py -m flask run
C:\Users\Nick\Documents\CPSC 362\project\SousChef\venv\Scripts\python.exe: No module named flask
(venv)
```

Thus far, it seems as far as I can tell, the 'FLASK_APP' and 'FLASK_ENV' both worked, but trying to run flask as the docs' tutorial suggests doesn't work - but running it with the '-m' tag gets a different error of conflicting server types.

This is doubly puzzling, because I was able to run a simple flask python file in another directory with no issue by following these directions (the exact same 'hello world' as on the tutorial in Flask's docs).

I was able to do the same with an earlier version of the project's **init**.py file, but not now that it has registered [Flask blueprints](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/views/).

Answer (score 0):

After much consternation, because I used Python's virtual environment, I had to do three things.

1. I had to open a virtual environment.
2. I had to install flask *inside* the virtual environment.
3. Once the virtual environment was up and running (using "source /Scripts/activate") I had to use the example code the tutorial uses for non-windows machines (though my laptop is on Windows).
   i.e.
   source venv/Scripts/activate
   export FLASK_APP=application
   export FLASK_ENV=development
   flask run